# LLdb error in Swift - How to fix it?

Tags: swift, lldb

I get a `lldb` error in Swift an don't know why. The code beneath worked fine but since yesterday the code causes an error.

Here's the error:

[image]

Do you know why I get this error?

Comment: Post the code not screenshots, with error

Comment: Here can you see the error. And in the console the error is `lldb`

Comment: lldb is your debugger. An lldb error is pretty much any error that isn't caught during build. You'll have to narrow this down a bit.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: Where can I see the exact error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @hulapalu: The console (the window at the bottom-center of Xcode) generally gives you the most readable description of an error. Also, telling us when and how the error occurs (build time, runtime, does it occur immediately upon run, after you load a view, after you perform an action, etc..., does it cause a crash or warning?) will help us to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Such errors are hard to fix when you are not providing much information.

**Option 1: Build Folder**

clean the Build Folder **Command+Option+Shift+K**.

**Option 2: Derived Data**

delete the Derived Data folder from

```
/Users/YourUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode
```

**Option 3: CocoaPods**

if you have a workspace with a pods project try this.
In Terminal:

```
cd /Your/Project/File/location
pod deintegrate
pod update
```

**Option 4: Through the code**

You are going to have to go through your code, setting breakpoints and pinpointing what exactly is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

In your picture you trimmed too much on the RHS.  Where it says "Thread 1:" there will have been text to the right of that which explains why the debugger stopped.

Most likely it said EXC_BAD_ACCESS with an address.  That stop reason means somebody tried to read or write to an invalid address - one that hasn't been allocated, or been allocated & freed.  If the address is 0x0 or somewhere near there, it probably means somebody is passing a NULL pointer where one is not expected.  If it is some higher address, that probably means the object you passed in or some ivar of same was bad (i.e. wasn't properly initialized or had been freed.)

Mentos's option 4 is likely in your future.  Again, if the crash was an bad access, it's likely something is wrong with the videoInput you are passing to addInput.

Note also, Xcode has a feature that compresses stack traces to show you only your code and frames near it.  That's why you only see the frame where you pass videoInput to AVCaptureSession, and the crashing frame.  The far left one of the three little widgets in the Filter section of the threads view will turn that off and show you all the frames.  You can sometimes glean a little more information about what is going on from the full stack trace.